# Xcode iPhone - Class that asks for multiple text inputs and then returns them

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I wan't to creata a "CatchNames" class which I can import into a view Controller that shows a text which asks for text input. I would like to be able to add an instance of CatchNames to my view, have it ask the user for three names in a row and return them in an array.

```
[self.view addSubview:[catchNames view]];
NSArray *myNamesArray = [catchNames namesArray];
```

The best way would be to have the application freeze kind of the way it does when you are prompted to enter a password in iOS and continue when the user entered 3 names so I can immediately catch the array in the next line.

While this might not be the best description I still hope you understand my problem.
How can I approach this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

I guess you appear to be looking to implement a simple form which gets the user input, retrieves and stores it in an array? Hopefully I haven't misunderstood the question, but this seems to be a simple task you can accomplish with one or more UITextField's and a UIButton as a 'Add' or 'Done' call to action.

Are you looking for some general UI coding level help regarding implementing such a view? If so, I would encourage taking a look at the XCode documentations of UITextField (for capturing text), UIButton (for handling actions) and UIView (for view hierarchy and animation implementation).

Some quick notes;

- Looks like 3 names are compulsory, so, you may verify whether a UITextField is empty at the button's click action.
- Have the array declared in the view controller, not the view
- The 'freezing' you require should take care of itself as long as the view offers no other way out for the user other than clicking the button.

Do excuse me if I am oversimplifying the problem. Let me know if you need me to drill down into anything further.

Cheers!

Comment: Hey Madhumal, thanks for your quick answer. I'm afraid the problem is a little more complex. I want the code to freeze after I added catchNames to the view and continue when the names where entered. That way I could implement the CatchNames class and work with the output in the next line of code without having to call a "finished" function from the subview which I do now.

Comment: Hi again, might I just ask whether you're having this code-freeze requirement for some specific reason? (Just trying to understand the scenario) Just checking since calling a separate delegate or function is the recommended method, and what we normally do.